# Check RDP protocol is allowed through a network from a webpage

Tags: java, javascript, html, networking, network-programming

There are some networks that block RDP protocol! To identify that the network allows RDP protocol, I thought to design a webpage from which running a test could tell the user that his network allows RDP.

I just need some ideas over it. Is it feasible to create a webpage like that? Any reference or inputs would be helpful!

Comment: Yes.  The test would probably be "can this host reach the rdp port on the host in question".

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen could you point to some reference please?

Comment: You need to learn how to use network communications in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't actually use RDP from a web browser if you haven't installed some tool like Guacamole or Chrome RDP on the remote machine. See [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/118872/remote-desktop-100-through-browser) related issue.

For a basic check I would suggest writing a Javascript tool which pings the ports required by RDP. By default these are TCP 3389 and UDP 3389.

Comment: I dont want to use RDP from web browser, instead just want to check the network allows RDP protocol, I dont think basic javascript tool could do that because, i just found [checkmyports.net](http://www.checkmyports.net/) shows 3389 is blocked in my network, but my network allows RDP. 

I might be wrong with interpreting your answer, please correct me

Comment: Well is the checkmyports.net server in your network or do you have the port forwarded? Otherwise it is no surprise the port is blocked.

Comment: yes.. i understood after some research.. Is there any solution with helps like java applet